# Ubuntu hotspot in my Dell Studio is not connecting to any device

Tags: internet, dell, hot-spot, wireless-access-point, dell-studio-xps-16

I have created Ubuntu Hotspot in my Ubuntu 20.04.2. When I tried to connect it to my Android phone or my other Laptop, "Joining "My-WiFI" timed out. please retry later."

My Laptop is Dell Studio 1450, old model with Intel core 2 duo, AMD graphics.

I feel it has something to do with "Access point", I am not sure.

Comment: When not acting as a hotspot, does it work properly? Have you confirmed the correct driver and firmware is in place? 

Comment: Yes. The wifi is working properly. I am trying to use this Laptop as hotspot using the LAN connection. It creates the hotspot but when I am trying to connect to any device (my phone or Laptop), it shows the error message. I am a beginner at Linux, so I am not sure about the drivers... I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 version. So, the drivers should be alright.